# Origin of "stop-gap"

Tags: etymology, expressions

What is the origin of the expression *stop-gap*?

> stop-gap: A temporary way of dealing with a problem or satisfying a
>   need

Where and how did this expression originate?

Comment: There is a gap somewhere.  As a temporary "fix" you jamb something into the gap to close it.  It's a stop-gap.  Might do it in a leaky boat, might do it in the wall of a house, might do it in a holey bucket.  And, of course, the metaphor caught on and carried to many other situations.

Answer (score 10):

According to [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stopgap), *stopgap* is an **adjectival use of the verb phrase "stop a gap"** (meaning, essentially, plug a hole) and emerged around 1525-1535.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stopgap?show=0&t=1317466556), though, has the first known use as 1684.

[Google Ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/ngrams/graph?content=stopgap&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows "stopgap" appearing briefly in the 1700s and disappearing again until the middle of the 1800s, at which point its use took off pretty dramatically, with a slight taper in the past 60 years.

Comment: The Ngram link has gone bad, but [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stop+gap&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstop%20gap%3B%2Cc0) is a newer one.

Comment: And I'll note that many of the early uses appear to use the term in the sense of filling in a gap in time, as with a temporary committee member.  (Though this may be a slant that occurs simply because of the types of documents indexed.)

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of staircases in old farmhouses can often be found 2 vertical slots at either side of the bottom tread. This was so that a plank of wood could be slotted in to prevent animals, often allowed into the ground floor of the house, from venturing up stairs. It was temporary to "stop the gap" - a stop gap.

Comment: Welcome to the site @CMann. Do you have any sources for your claim?

Comment: And how would this lead to the metaphoric meaning of "stop gap" as an ad-hoc "temporary fix", since the slots are presumably permanent, and the scheme took some advance planning?

Answer (score -1):

Stop gap,from the use of a large piece of wet timber put in front of the gap on a bread oven,abit like a pizza oven,it was the whole in the front of the oven called the gape which the piece of wood,the stop was placed