# Noun for "that which is reluctantly settled for because of the unavailability or impossiblilty of attaining that which was truly desired"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests

This happens to me a lot, but I can't seem to find the right noun for it.

In the saying "A string is useful until a rope could be found," what would you call the string? That's the noun I'm looking for.

In relationships, I don't think I want to end up being someone's *_* because she couldn't find that special someone she truly wanted.

O, yes, and adjective form, too?

Comment: That's very close to the technical term _to satisfice_, a blend of _satisfy_ and _suffice_. There is no emotional component to the verb, however; it doesn't say anybody is reluctant or what anybody truly desires. Simple economic assumptions only.

Comment: ....second best

Comment: Also see  [Is there a single noun in English for "jerry-rigged"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/94806),  [Is there a word for temporary-but-may-become-permanent?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/66134), and  [Origin of "stop-gap"](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/43893)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two French phrases which have become largely naturalized in English—to the extent, at least, that they are not ordinarily printed in italics:

- *pis aller*, used as a nominal : literally "worst going", a stopgap or last resort
- *faute de mieux*, usually adverbial but occasionally adjectival :  for lack of anything better

Faute de mieux comes closer in sense to what you want, and if you took the liberty afforded by its Anglicization to employ it as a nominal only the most negligible pedants would reproach you.

Answer (score 1):

The string could be called a "stop-gap measure" or a "stop-gap solution."

For example, a string would be a good stop-gap measure for stanching a bleeder, but a rope would make a better tourniquet if it's available.

In other words, a string will do "in a pinch," but when you are not constrained by time or an emergency, locating and using the right rope (or a "real" tourniquet) is a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

When planning, one could have a fallback, also known as a backup or contingency plan.  As for relationships, you're looking for the negative form, which may be referred to as the 'rebound' (slang), or perhaps also fallback- or goto- girl/guy.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to end up being someone's **second choice**. If it happens often, you will begin to feel like a **second class** person. This could be due to the quality of your work, which might be *second rate*.

A sting may suffice as an **alternative** to a rope.

Answer (score 0):

In modern use 'adequacy' is normally a non-count noun which refers to the quality of being adequate.

> He would not settle for **adequacy**.

However, it could also be used as a count noun to refer to the object itself, although this usage is rare/archaic.

> The string was an **adequacy** until a rope could be found.

Although rare, I think most people would understand this usage in context.