# what do you call something that was created to solve a problem

Tags: nouns, terminology

what do you call something that was created to solve a problem?

**Let's use the operating system as an example:**

1. Before the operating system was invented, developers needed to implement really basic programs for each application, like getting user key input and displaying corresponding texts on the screen, resulting in high cost of developing software...
2. The operating system was invented in order to solve this problem.
3. Its solution to the problem was to provide programs that had basic functionalities that every application needs.

So, you can say, the essence of OS is "a set of programs that have basic functionalities that every application needed".

**QUESTION**
In this example, solution is "to create and provide a set of programs that have basic functionalities that every application needs, which is, the operating system". I don't want "to create and provide" part. I just want a word that just means the operating system in this context. Not a solution coz it includes verbs too. I am feeling like this needs to be explanatory, like "a thing that was created to solve a problem".
I don't even know how it's called in my mother tongue actually.

Comment: @niamulbengali true, man

Comment: If 'solution' is an/the answer, this is too basic for ELL. Otherwise, probably a duplicate of [Is there a noun for addressing a problem but not quite a solution?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/349197/is-there-a-noun-for-addressing-a-problem-but-not-quite-a-solution) and duplicate. 'Not enough details given' is probably the sensible CV reason.

Comment: Actually, the link-loader was invented to solve those problems.  The OS came along later.

Answer (score 0):

Well the obvious answer to your question and to any problem is its **solution**.

> ... each application developer
> needed to implement really basic programs, like getting user key input
> and displaying corresponding texts on the screen, resulting in high
> cost of developing software...

The **solution/remedy/answer** to this problem was the operating system.

Less formally

The **fix** for this problem was the operating system.

---

If you want a short way of saying

> "a set of programs that have basic functionalities that every
> application needs"

Then clearly the answer is **operating system**.

---

If this is not what you want then please explain where it falls short. Thank you.

P.S. The question in the title of your post is not the same as the question at the end. This is confusing.

Comment: A site aimed at linguists. I'm trying to find one where that principle is respected.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
In this example, solution is "to create and provide the operating system". I don't want "to create and provide" part. I just want a word that means the operating system in this context. Not a solution. I am feeling like this needs to be explanatory, like a thing that was created to solve a problem.

Comment: *"Well the obvious answer to your question and to any problem is its solution."* Not really. The obvious answer is an attempted or purported solution. There are plenty of things that were created to solve a problem but don't solve it. Those are not solutions.

Comment: @anonyrabbit The verb is "solve", and "solution" is the result of that process.